# Is it acceptable to contact a recruiter directly after a year if they mentioned the company would follow-up in a year?

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, follow-up

A year ago I applied for a job at a company and after the onsite interview, the company decided not to give me the job. They said the feedback was still good though and they see a lot of potential so they said within a year they would follow-up again to see where I am at.

It's been a few months past a year now and I was interested in applying again. I still have the recruiters contact information (specifically email) and was wondering if it would be off-putting or strange to contact him/her directly to see if there were any opportunities again? I'm not sure if them not following up is a sign they aren't interested anymore and might come off the wrong way of me directly reaching out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer yes. Following up with a recruiter to see if you could interview again is perfectly fine. A recruiter's job is to get a company that best candidates for their open positions, so they will at least entertain your email.

It doesn't hurt to be more proactive if you really want this position.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all, in fact the recruiter would probably be delighted in that they're talking to somebody that's not a cold call.

However, and there's always a however with recruiters, your best bet is to contact the company directly to cut out the middle man (the recruiter).

Lastly, be prepared for an instant rejection if there's no open positions, but don't take it personally either.

Comment: When you say contact the "contact the company", who is that exactly? To clarify the recruiter I am speaking with is a recruiter from the company.

Comment: Then call him directly. RandomUs1r was referring to a recruting agency, which it seems you are not using.

Comment: @UsernameNotFound so its acceptable to just call the recruiters directly? That's actually why I ask because to me it seems a little too forward but if that's acceptable, then thanks a lot! :)